# ImportError; Issue installing Reportlab 3.4 with Python 3.5 in PyCharm

Tags: python, installation, reportlab

I am trying to run Reportlab 3.4 in Python 3.5 in PyCharm

I installed via Project Interpreter (and I also installed via Terminal). When I try to import the following packages

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import portrait
from reportlab.platypus import Image
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'reportlab.pdfgen'; 'reportlab' is not a package
```

It seems that several people had this issue a few years back but I cannot find a recent example of this happening.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. The import statements worked if I typed them directly into the interpreter, but if I tried to execute my program from a file I got import errors stating: ImportError...'reportlab' is not a package. These import conflicts arise if you name your script reportlab.py, you just have to rename it to something else.